# Create partition for Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, windows, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I have a full ubuntu installation on my hard drive. But im in need of windows 7 too now. I found this guide on askubuntu:

[How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

But when it comes to the second sentence in answers section im lost as to how i will do this.

"Second, boot the ubuntu desktop CD, resize your partitions, and make a NTFS partition for Windows"

is there a guide out there that will show me the right way without losing all my files?

Comment: It says  to create a bootable [Live Cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or USB Drive of Ubuntu using the Ubuntu ISO image.

Comment: you can install virtualbox and install windows 7 in a virtual machine or check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you're getting at is the creation of the NTFS partition rather than how to install Windows 7.

Your best bet would be to re-size your partition using gparted to free up space for windows. Then put your windows disc in and go through a custom install. There will be an option to create your new NTFS partition there in the empty space.

Just be aware that windows will wipe out your boot info for Ubuntu so you will have to stick a ubuntu live disc in after installing windows 7 and repair your grub loader as per the instructions at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation) or [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub/Ripristino&act=url)

Comment: Thank you for replying, installing windows 7 is not a problem and repairing grub is easy as it is explained in the guide posted, but i just want to know if there is a guide out there for resizing because i dont know where to start and i cant afford to lose existing ubuntu installation, Thank you.

Comment: To re size your ubuntu partition you will need to boot from a ubuntu live disc as you can't modify a partition while it is in use. Then from the live disc run gparted and follow the instructions here http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: As was already suggested - the least hazard to your Ubuntu data is to install Windows in a virtual machine. If not for 3D graphics intense games or for hardware manipulation such as firmware upgrades it will give you quite a decent performance.