# How do I preserve Xubuntu while installing Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Im looking to get Windows 7 Starter running on my laptop again as a Dual Boot so that I can run some windows programs that Wine and Cross-over wont run. What would be the best advice on how to do this?

I have a Key that i can use from when i originally got the laptop and I can only use USB to install. Ive heard that installing Windows can wipe out Xubuntu completely and you have to install Xubuntu again (not sure if its true or not) but would like to avoid this as I dont have much free time to be sorting out everything all over again.

Comment: I suggest you to re-phrase the question along the lines "how do I preserve Xubuntu while installing Windows" or the question is quickly going to be closed as off-topic :)

Comment: I would suggest looking at the following: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation