# Ubuntu and Windows7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I know, this is a stupid question but I need your help.

I have ubuntu 12.04 on my Computer but I need windows to play Metin2 (yes I need because I am gamemaster). Wine doesn't work because of hackshield's error 108 (no fix found).

Ok.
So when I installed Ubuntu, I have selected just a half of my HDD (the rest is unformated/free.

Now, when I install Windows, the grub loader will be owerwritten by windows bootloader... right?

I need all my files and don't want to loose this installed ubuntu because of skype(it took 2 days to configure the sound and my external microphone).

Do somebody know how to install grubloader AFTER the windows installation? Or can me somebody give me step-by-step instructions to install windows?

I'm newbie and this is asked many times but I found just how to install ubuntu after windows or problem with windows installation.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the marked partition for windows? I just want to be sure... [link](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3402/bildschirmfotovom201305.png)

Comment: There's no such thing as a stupid question as long as it fits with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). ;-)

Comment: Step by step instructions (for win7)can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu from a live CD, keep that handy. If not, download the .iso and make one so you can run Ubuntu from disc after installing Windows.

If you are only going to be using Windows for Metin2 and little else, you may want to evaluate the current status of your partition sizes. Windows doesn't like being resized (disk checks and other possible hiccups), so if you're gonna use gparted to resize it's best to do it before installing Windows.

Install Windows into your unpartitioned disk space. Put in your Ubuntu live CD. Then follow the steps in the link referred to you by psusi in the comments.

EDIT: I almost forgot. Of course, you'll wanna back up your valuables before using gparted on any operating system. I've never had any problems with resizing or moving Ubuntu, but that doesn't mean it couldn't happen. Also, if you have the time or desire and you haven't already done it, it's good practice to put your /home folder on a separate partition. That way if you ever have to or want to reinstall Ubuntu you won't have to copy your personal stuff back and forth.