# The Partitioning Tool doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot

I've tried different ways to get the 12.04 version onto my new laptop.

I'm able to boot from CD, but this is only good for the session.

When I try to install Alongside Windows, the section where we the partioning tool should come up and ask me if I want to do alongside Windows, do a complete Ubuntu install or something else.  But only some new tool, that looks like I'm supposed to do the partioning myself.  Yikes!!  But even then, the buttons for ADD, NEW Table, DELETE, REVERT, etc, weren't getting any response.

This is a new laptop, so there's plenty of room.  But I need to apparently partition this Windows Professional drive...manually.

How can I get this done?
Any guidance, links, etc. would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the partitioning tool does not work from the installer, then yes, you will have to do manual partitioning.

Boot into windows, defragement your hard drive. Next resize your windows C: drive, leave the remaining space as free space.

Then boot the Ubuntu live CD and install Ubuntu into the free space. At that point, the installer should automatically make the partitions needed. If not, make a swap partition the size of your RAM + 512 Mb. The rest would be for Ubuntu root, also called /

For details and an extended discussion see:

[How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Yep first resize partition in Windows, then boot from Ubuntu Disk. Install it alongside Windows. Windows bootloader is replace by Grub2 (on old BIOS computers), which can boot not only Linux, but also Windows.