# Ubuntu on Dell 6430u 256 SSD

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, dell

I am new to Ubuntu and looking for a suitable Laptop to run it. Could anyone give me his/her experience with a

- Dell Latitude 6430u Intel Core i3 256 SSD and Ubuntu 12.04? I would like to run it in dual boot mode with Windows 7.
- Dell XPS 13 256 SSD? I have not found an Ubuntu release for this model, but Dell offers a version with pre-installed 12.04. Can I install Windows 7 alongside?

Any recommendations for another model? Thank you, Nils

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Latitude 6430u is [certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201208-11536/) to work with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, but it has a few notes you should read about things that might not work. The Dell XPS 13 256 SSD is also [certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201209-11840/) for Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. If you want to install Windows 7 along side an Ubuntu installation you will want to follow [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation).