# Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 PROBLEM

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have spent the past 4 days trying to get Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my computer and every time it boots straight into Ubuntu. I have looked through most of the threads and tried Windows first, Ubuntu first, partitioning the drive, reinstall grub with boot - repair, pretty much every tutorial I can find, I only have one USB drive to boot off of, so this is very time consuming. I have to download the iso file and create a bootable USB everytime I install an OS and it's all for nothing because there is no boot menu. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, I found the answer [here](http://forums.scotsnewsletter.com/index.php?showtopic=45226) to get the grub menu to show up.

If anyone is reading this and has the same problem I mentioned above, follow the first answer in the link and it should be good to go. I am now getting a menu and am able to boot into Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu you can manually add Windows 7 to your GRUB menu:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Follow instructions [in this article on technologytales.com](http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/). Or you could try a GUI program [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

Comment: Nope, it still boots straight into Ubuntu with no Boot menu. Just to clarify, I used this thread to install Windows 7:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation

By the way, when editing this file, the set root line is supposed to point to the partition that Windows is installed on (In my case, sda2), correct? And the hd0 represents the first hard disk? I didn't quite understand this when reading through the instructions.

Comment: The answer  is yes to both questions.