# How to install windows on a partition of a secondary hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have two hard drives, one of which (`sda`) is a 30 GiB SSD, the other (`sdb`) is a 930 GiB HDD. I have some unallocated space at the end of `sdb` that I want to install windows to.

Here is a picture explaining it:

[image: Main boot disk]
[image: Secondary data disk]

What is the easiest way to install windows into that space? I want `sda` to be my main boot disk, and use GRUB from there to launch either my main ubuntu install, or my windows install.

Also, is there a good way to help preserve my `/data` partition? While I agree that a backup is the best option, my backup options are limited, as the only storage device I have that is big enough is limited to a 10MB/s upload, meaning it would take nearly 10 hours to make a backup. (That, plus the fact that most of the data I store there is barely even worth storing *once*, let alone twice. Rest assured that I will be backing up any actually important data regardless of what else I do.)

I have read [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation) and [Install on Second Hard Drive with startup boot option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option), but neither quite answer my question.

Comment: From past history I would say it is impossible. Windows needs to be on the 1st partition of a disc. Why are you asking this on a site dedicated to Ubuntu? Would it not be better to ask this to users of the Windows system if this is possible?

Comment: @Rinzwind I looked, but I'm pretty sure there isn't a Windows stackexchange.

Comment: @Rinzwind Also, [this document](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-multiple-operating-system-multiboot) indicates that the "must be first partition" is just a limitation of the windows bootloader, not something intrinsic to the windows system. Using GRUB to launch windows should allow this to work.

Comment: Yes there is: http://superuser.com/ is windows ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind oh great, thanks. Unfortunately I can't vote for migration because I don't have enough rep for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems more practical is:

Disconnect the hard disk /dev/sda.

Install Windows in the free space of /dev/sdb (now /dev/sda)

Reconnect hard disk /dev/sda

Run to incorporate Windows to Grub:

```
sudo -i
update-grub
```

Comment: Sounds good; that's probably what I will do unless somebody comes up with an even better solution.