# How can I install Ubuntu onto a second hard drive along side windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive

I've recently managed to install my old PC hard drive and have formatted it, now I want to install Ubuntu onto it but I don't want anything to happen to my windows 7 hard drive. I want to be able to boot either windows 7 or Ubuntu when I start up my PC. I want to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive not my first, I plan on using a boot-able USB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon installing Ubuntu it will detect that you have another OS on your hard drive and will ask you weather you want to run Ubuntu along side with it or remove it and install Ubuntu. It will also allow you choose the suitable size for your Ubuntu. 
Just make sure that you know how much your C drive -in windows- needs in order not to "harm" it.

Comment: So when I actually do it I will select my other hard drive which is D drive and my main windows 7 one is C drive. So my C drive isnt affected.

Comment: It will detect that you have a windows OS on your PC and it's size (C+D drive) and will then ask you how much you want to shrink it and put Ubuntu on the empty space.
Don't worry it will probably be safe to do :D
however it is always recommended to have a backup for your windows (which I never used)