# Windows 10 Factory Reset: risk for Grub and dual boot partitions?

Tags: grub2, windows-10, reset

I just have a quick question. If I choose to factory reset my pc. (Lenovo Thinkpad Windows 10). Will Grub2 also be deleted, along with my Linux dual boot?

Comment: Possbly helpful: [Can I safely restore Windows while keeping my Linux partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/633144/301745)

Comment: I repeat, the **linked question and answers are about Windows 7, this is about Windows 10** where there is a new feature that works different and there is also a difference in the type of bootloader these computers ship by default (UEFI). So by default this does not qualify as a duplicate of the provided question.