# can I get Windows 10 over Ubuntu because I have Ubuntu and I want Windows back

Tags: dual-boot

Right now I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I want to get Windows 10 on it. I don't want it in a window on Linux. I want it so that when I turn my computer on it is there. I have the ISO right now what do I do? Windows 10 is free so I don't need the key for so I don't have to buy a new windows. I have look at all the question people have said and the answers are not helping. (don't care about the GUI for booting to Linux)

Comment: If you don't need anything from your current GNU/linux setup, you just have to install windows, like if there was nothing on the drive. But, as you don't need to do anything in Ubuntu to achieve that, your question is off topic here.

Comment: to extend the existing answer: an upgrade of an existing legal copy of Windows 7 or 8 to Windows 10 is free as part of the upgrade offer that is currently still available. Most of the computers today have the licensing information in the firmware (previously called BIOS), so it may appear "free" for the casual user, but it's wrong. It's unclear to me how your question relates to Ubuntu or Linux in general, especially when you already have downloaded the ISO from Microsoft, what do you need Linux users for to explain how to read the rest of the instructions Microsoft provides?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.... I just understood that you want to replace Ubuntu with Windows 10!

1. If you are willing to **completely remove** Ubuntu and install Windows, you will find a detailed answer here : [**How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)
2. If you are willing to **dual boot** Windows alongside Ubuntu, you will find great answers here : [**How do I install Windows alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

**Note : Windows 10 is not FREE!**  In your question, you have said:

> Windows 10 is free so I don't need the key

Please read Microsoft's terms and conditions : [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/features) (mentioned at the bottom  "Windows Offer Details" )