# How to partition my drive in ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I wanted to install ubuntu is along side 
windows but my windows were erased somehow. Anyway, I have windows cd but not partition to install it in dual-boot. SO can u pls tell me how I can partition my drive. And pls don't tell me to install windows completely over ubuntu and then install ubuntu ok. BTW thank u.

Answer (score 0):

- For windows to be installed alongside ubuntu first you need to make the partition of the format NTFS in your ubuntu
- you can do it using gparted application in ubuntu.
- After this start booting your windows.
- then install windows on that particular NTFS partition.
- for more info go here [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a partition on the existing drive if it is mounted. You need to create a live usb and boot into the live Ubuntu. Then follow these steps:

- Open terminal, `ctrl` + `alt` + `t`.
- Type `sudo gparted`.
- Resize your drive.
- Set the format's for the new unallocated memory space.
- Reboot back into your normal Ubuntu.

Then follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) to install windows on top of your new partition.