# WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB

Tags: windows, ntfs, mint, usb-installation, woeusb

I tried to create a Windows 10 USB boot medium with WoeUSB. I formatted a USB drive with an NTFS partition, but WoeUSB complains with:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Error: File "/media/woeusb_source_1543626298_6098/sources/install.wim" in
source image has exceed the FAT32 Filesystem 4GiB Single File Size Limitation
and cannot be installed.  You must specify a different --target-filesystem.
Refer: https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/wiki/Limitations#fat32-filesystem-4gib-single-file-size-limitation for more info.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1543626298_6098"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

I've also tried to start WoeUSB via command line, did not work.

```
sudo woeusb --partition Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso /dev/sdb
```

My iso is located in:
    home/sawyer/Downloads/Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso

Thanks in advance! I've been trying to get windows installed for three nights now, so any help towards that goal is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 35):

### Edit 6: a major edit

#### Now we talk about the [github version of `woeusb`](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/tag/v5.1.3)

The github version is at 5.1.3 and works in Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS (and 18.04.x LTS, probably all current versions of Ubuntu, but I have not tested them).

#### PPA version of `woeusb` deprecated

Please be aware that the `woeusb` PPA version at `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` is deprecated (works in Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS but fails in 20.04.x LTS). Today (2021-11-07) it is at version 3.3.1 (dated 2020-02-13).

#### Test

- From the [WoeUSB github](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/tag/v5.1.3) I downloaded and tested `woeusb-5.1.3.bash` as well as the version in the tarball. They differ only in the line specifying the version. So I used the separate version with explicit version number.
- I used the command line

  ```
  sudo ./woeusb-5.1.3.bash --target-filesystem NTFS --device Windows11.iso /dev/sdx
  ```
- `wimlib-imagex` was not found, and `woeusb` quit. It can be installed from the repository universe with the command

  ```
  sudo apt install wimtools
  ```

  It is needed, when installing into a FAT32 file system in order to split the huge `install.wim` file, but when selecting NTFS, the installation should continue without `wimtools`. That way the WoeUSB bash shellscript will work without `wimtools` (but it wants an internet connection in order to get `uefi-ntfs.img`).
- The USB drive with Windows installer

  - created in 18.04.6 LTS and 20.04.3 LTS
  - boots both

    - in UEFI mode (also with secure boot) and
    - in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode).

### end of Edit 6

**I tested the current `woeusb` from the PPA** (running a persistent live Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS), and the following command lines work for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb

sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device path/windows.iso /dev/sdx
```

In my case the iso file was in `/media/lubuntu/usbdata/images/` and the target device was `/dev/sdb`, but in your case **check carefully that you will write to the intended drive** (avoid destroying valuable data in some other drive),

```
sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /media/lubuntu/usbdata/images/windows.iso /dev/sdb
```

Notice that all partitions on the target device must be unmounted.

---

The created USB boot drive has a small FAT partition (for UEFI boot) and a big NTFS partition with the Windows files. It can install Windows both in BIOS and UEFI mode with `woeusb 3.2.10.1` (dated 2018-09-19 (Sept 19 2018) in the PPA).

Using NTFS makes it is possible to use file size > 4 GiB. The size of `install.wim` is

- smaller than 4 GiB in some of Microsoft's own iso files, for example in
- `Win10_1809Oct_Swedish_x64.iso`

  ```
       $ <<<'scale=3;4274234443/2^30' bc
       3.980                              # < 4 GiB
  ```
- greater than 4 GiB for some iso files for particular computers, OEM, but also in several of Microsoft's own iso files, for example
- `Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso`

  ```
       $ <<<'scale=3;4396229344/2^30' bc
       4.094                              # > 4 GiB
  ```
- `Win10_1809Oct_EnglishInternational_x64.iso`

  ```
       $ <<<'scale=3;4386496792/2^30' bc
       4.085
  ```
- `Win10_1809Oct_German_x64.iso`

  ```
       $ <<<'scale=3;4401709065/2^30' bc
       4.099
  ```
- `Win10_1809Oct_Spanish_x64.iso`

  ```
       $ <<<'scale=3;4404104344/2^30' bc
       4.101
  ```

---

There is also a GUI version `woeusbgui`. I don't think is has the option to create a target drive with a FAT file system for UEFI plus an NTFS filesystem, so I would recommend using the command line version `woeusb`.

---

**Edit 1**:

You can **do it yourself** with detailed help at

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files)

This method works in both BIOS and UEFI mode and also with secure boot. (But in most cases it should be possible to turn off secure boot, use the drive created by `woeusb`, and turn on secure boot again.)

**Edit 2**:

Thanks @John for your comment that **there should be no space character in the source file name**. If there is you can rename the file, and then `woeusb` works.

> Thanks @qbit. This did not solve my problem but your idea of a parsing
> error helped me to realize that it does not like having a space in the
> source filename. That got me to move one step forward.

**Edit 3**:

There is a problem in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
$ LANG=C sudo apt install woeusb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Until this problem with `woeusb` is solved, you can use **mkusb-plug** according to this link:

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug)

The tool **`mkusb-tow`** of mkusb-plug is now available also via dus (mkusb version 12.5.6). See this link

[mkusb 12.5.6 with new installer for Windows](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13961108#post13961108)

**Edit 4**:

A set of workaround commands for woeusb in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is described in the following link,

[NTFS partition service issue with creating Windows 10 bootable USB on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243564/how-can-i-create-windows-bootable-usb-for-old-systems-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-foss)

**Edit 5**:

Today (2021-10-16) I tested that [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) can create working installer drives from a Windows 11 iso file.

Comment: This answer also worked for me. For those who are unsure how to unmount, I did this in the command line. Use `lsblk` to determine where your USB device is.  In my case it was `sdd1`, and I did `sudo umount /dev/sdd1`. After, I used the command above to create the USB.  Note that I had to remove the `1` from the drive, so at the very end of the `woeusb` command, I used `/dev/sdd`.

Comment: I guess it's just the GUI. I formatted my USB to NTFS and followed instructions with GUI and get this error every time. Using the command line with flags is the only way to get this to work in Ubuntu 18.04 with the current PPA. Seems like the GUI only knows how to format to FAT, and ignores that the partition is already formatted to NTFS.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't reproduce the error as running that command produced a different error (`check_runtime_parameters: Error: Target media "/dev/sdb" is not an partition!`).

What seemed to work was to wipe and build a boot drive from scratch with:

`sudo woeusb --tgt-fs NTFS -d ~/Downloads/Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 2):

Some third-party installers, like your Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso, feature Windows installation images greater than 4GB making FAT32 as target filesystem impossible. NTFS filesystem support has been added to **WoeUSB 3.0.0 and later**. If your version of WoeUSB is earlier than 3.0 please update it. The latest version of WoeUSB at time of posting this answer is 3.3.1.

For WoeUSB v3.0 and later the `--format` command-line option is no longer available.

Try opening woeusbgui from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo -H woeusbgui &>/dev/null
```

Comment: My USB is 8GB. My interpretation of the warning was that FAT32 formatted USB's can not handle files larger than 4GB, so it's necessary to format in NTFS. Thing is, I have formatted my USB in NTFS, but it's like WoeUSB can't see that.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me. I was trying to create a Windows 7 USB using woeusb on 18.04. I tried the gui, cli, tried formatting, not formatting, tried different parameter ordering... nothing worked.

Finally, [qbit's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126344/551485) gave me the idea that there might be a parsing problem. I noticed my iso filename contained spaces. I renamed the file so that there were no spaces (renamed to WINDOWS7.ISO) and then the cli version finally started to copy files (did not try the gui). However, it crashed at the end.

Finally, I used the Windows.iso in VirtualBox to create a Windows VM. Then **I used rufus.exe to write the iso to a USB through Windows**. This did work and I got a laptop setup with Windows that day.

I never did get woeusb to work. Hopefully, the author(s) will fix it as there does not seem to be any other utility which runs under Ubuntu to create a Windows boot USB.

I had installed woeusb through the ppa. After I posted this answer, I noticed that woeusb updated. After the update to the latest version, I find that woeusb now writes successfully for both Win7 and Win10 iso.

So, before trying my answer, try updating woeusb.

Comment: +1: Your final comment may be correct concerning current versions of  Wndows 10, but [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works with Windows 7, Windows 8 and early Windows 10 iso files (when `install.wim` size does not exceed 4 GiB). It is strange that `woeusb` works for me and many other people but not for you. Maybe it works for you too, if you try with Windows 10 (but obviously not with Windows 7).

Comment: @sudodus I actually tried several versions of Windows 10 and then gave up and tried Windows 7. I could get neither Windows 7 or 10 to work with woeusb. Maybe something unique about my setup (but I think mine is pretty standard, other than using Budgie desktop)

Comment: @sudodus Interestingly, woeusb just updated on my machine (since my earlier problems) and now it creates the USB just fine (I tested both Win7 and Win10). So, perhaps I should revise my answer to "Update woeusb" :-)

Comment: Yes @John, it is a good idea to revise your answer to "Update woeusb". Thanks again for sharing your experience :-) By the way, today, 2020-02-15, my version in Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS according to `apt-cache policy woeusb` is 3.3.0-1~webupd8~bionic0

Answer (score 1):

Out of some unknown reason, the above things solutions https://askubuntu.com/a/1098185/846139 or https://askubuntu.com/a/1098076/846139 did not work for me as expected.

There seems to be a **problem with the argument parsing** in `woeusb` v3.2.12.

Putting that target filsystem option at the beginning did not work in self-built WoeUSB v3.2.12 on ubuntu 18.10 cosmic.

**What did work**, however:

```
sudo woeusb -d  /somewhere/Win10_abcd_xy_x64.iso /dev/sdb --target-filesystem ntfs
```

Comment: Interesting :-) `woeusb` works well for me in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and the same version of  `woeusb` seems to be ported to the PPA for 18.10. Did you try your command line with `--target-filesystem ntfs` at the end also with the version from the PPA?

Comment: the ppa version does funny things:
    $ woeusb --version
    @@WOEUSB_VERSION@@

Comment: and **yes**, the ppa version `WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@` (3.2.12-1~webupd8~cosmic0) also *accepts the appended* `--target-filesystem` option

**but NOT** when given as *second option* `sudo woeusb -d --target-filesystem ntfs ...`

Comment: @John, Thanks for sharing this important information. If you undelete your answer I will upvote it :-)

Comment: @John, I see. But you have removed one possible obstacle. Anyway, If you have tough luck with `woeusb` I can suggest two alternative ways: 1. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) that can be expected to work with Windows 7, 8 and early Windows 10. But the current versions of Windows 10 contain a file with size > 4 GiB, and mkusb is not (yet?) made for that. An alternative is to do it [manually according to this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy)

Comment: @John, ps/ Sometimes, even when `woeusb` throws and error, the USB drive will actually work. Did you test it? /ds

Comment: @John, Please let us know if you succeeded with Rufus in the VM.

Comment: @sudodus I wrote up all my comments as an answer, for future visitors (and to keep the comment thread cleaner).