# WoeUSB Installation failed! Exit Code 256. Trying to install Windows 10 on USB from a laptop running 14.04

Tags: usb, windows-10, ntfs, woeusb

I am trying to build a new computer and run Windows 10 on it. I've run into a snag, and can't get the ISO on a USB flash drive using my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. When trying to download the ISO onto 16GB USB flash drive I get the following error message:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Error: File "/media/woeusb_source_1544835295_14348/sources/install.wim" in source image has exceed the FAT32 Filesystem 4GiB Single File Size Limitation and cannot be installed.  You must specify a different --target-filesystem.
Refer: https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/wiki/Limitations#fat32-filesystem-4gib-single-file-size-limitation for more info.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1544835295_14348"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

It says the USB is formatted to FAT32 but I have installed GParted and formatted it to NTFS. I've actually formatted it several different ways trying to following other users on here, and I keep getting various error codes when using WoeUSB.

[image: what I am seeing]

Comment: It's pretty much the same question, but none of the answers listed in that post have worked. It also asks to refrain from asking questions that aren't clarification. Thus I have created a new question trying to get to the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours.
The following link is a buttery smooth flow to fix this issue.
https://medium.com/@codechangetheworld/build-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-in-linux-501f92e346a5

With this flow, I was able to build UEFI bootable windows 10, 1803 Apr 2018 image(~4.3GB) in Ubuntu 16.xx environment.  Hope this works for you too...

Comment: I think the problem in this question is that a file inside the iso file, `install.wim`, is too big for the FAT32 file system. And in such cases, the graphical (GUI) version of `woeusb` does not work, at least one month ago. If I understand correctly, the link you are referring to is using the graphical version. In your case, even if the iso file exceeds 4 GiB, the biggest file inside it is probably smaller than that limiting size. See [WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185)