# Can't find my bootable USB as an option in the UEFI options

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I'm using a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I tried to make a bootable USB after downloading the Windows 10 ISO file, but it doesn't appear as an option in the UEFI bootable screen.

I didn't use woeusb or any other program as I couldn't install them. I just made it using the Disks utility, then I formatted it as FAT32 then used **Restore Disk Image and restored the Windows ISO file. Is this a correct method of making a bootable USB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) and [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/)

Comment: Why could you not install woeusb or any other program? Do you lack superuser permissions (can you log in as root or run sudo or not)? Or is there some other problem, that prevents you from installing programs?

Answer (score 2):

Cloning works with Ubuntu iso files but it does not work with Windows 10 iso files. You must use some other tool, for example `mkusb` (if you have an iso file downloaded from Microsoft), or `woeusb` (if you have a custom iso file where the file `install.wim` exceeds 4 GiB).

- Install `mkusb` into your Ubuntu according to the following link,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for live standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```
- Install `woeusb` into your Ubuntu and run it according to the following link,

  [WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185)