# Trying to split "install.wim" while creating a Windows bootable usb

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to reinstall windows on my laptop by creating a bootable USB but when I try to move the files from the disk image mounter, but the file "Install.wim" is too large. I've done some research and learned about wimsplit so I ran.

```
$ wimsplit install.wim install.swm 1000 --check
```

and the output was this

```
[WARNING] "install.wim" does not contain integrity information.  Skipping integrity check.
Writing "install.swm" (part 1 of 5): 0 MiB of 4358 MiB (0%) written
[ERROR] Failed to open "install.swm" for writing: Read-only file system
ERROR: Exiting with error code 47:
       Failed to open a file.
```

I cant really find a answer to a solution. please help

Comment: I know this may seem a bit convoluted but for installing windows usb sticks can only be made by windows. this is by design. So your best bet is to borrow someone else's windows computer to make your usb key.

Comment: You can try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185).

Comment: duplicate of [Windows 10 bootable USB drive when install.wim >4GiB](https://superuser.com/questions/1392217/windows-10-bootable-usb-drive-when-install-wim-4gib)

Answer (score 5):

You were SOOOO close. The trouble is you need to specify a path NOT in the ISO which I'd imagine you probably have loop mounted. You don't really need the `--check` option either, as it can make the process take quite a while longer, but it doesn't hurt.

Check out the write-up I put together of the whole process including how to do it on a system where maybe you don't have access to loop mount an ISO.

https://gist.github.com/dragon788/26921410d8de054366188c5c5435ae01

Comment: Wow! Nice solution. Magical 'wimsplit' tool. Most other techniques I found were either too complicated or did not work :}