# Windows 7 usb created using ubuntu image writter not booting

Tags: usb, windows

Using ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 I created a windows 7 install usb using image writter.   It will not boot.   Ie: boots into the grub for ubuntu but no way does the win7 usb get booted.   I am new to ubuntu.   I can not get unetbootin to install.   Added repository and all.   So can someone point me to something that will help or tell me if it's possible to create windows install usb on ubuntu?   I do not have a windows computer only ubuntu.   I have set boot order ect ect.   Pleaae respond and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used "sudo cp isofile /dev/somedevice" where "somedevice" is the root device of your usb drive, aka sdb, sdc, etc.  Do not use the partition identifier such as "sdc1", just the device itself "sdc", or whichever one points to your device.

Some people will tell you to use dd, and that works fine, but I've had one or two experiences where dd broke a drive in such a way that it wouldn't work outside of Linux.  dd makes the entire thumb drive, no matter its capacity, look like it's a CD-ROM of the exact size of the ISO file you feed into it, so if you have a 32GB thumb drive and you dd a 2GB ISO file to it, your thumb drive will look like it's a 2GB CD-ROM device with no free space left.  cp accomplishes the same goal of putting an ISO on a USB device and making it bootable (erasing any existing data on the drive in the process), but it creates a partition for the ISO file and leaves the rest of the drive alone so it can be reused/reformatted more easily in a Windows environment.

So anyway, try "sudo cp isofilename /dev/somedevice" to put your Windows ISO on a usb stick.  For me personally, that has worked at times when other methods such as Etcher, unetbootin, tuxboot, etc. all failed to produce a bootable device.

Comment: Thank you so much!   I'll try when I get back to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work to clone a Windows 7 or newer iso file to a USB drive. You need a tool to create a bootable installer (or do the extracting work manually and create a bootloader).

---

You can try **mkusb** according to the following links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)

or **woeusb** according to the following links

[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/489556#489556) - see 'Ubuntu 14.04 and later' (by @karel)

[WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185)

---

I don't think Windows 7 has any problem with a huge file inside the iso file.