# Make Windows bootable pendrive from Ubuntu using woeusb and unetbootin

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows-10, iso

I installed Ubuntu a month ago, then decided to reinstall Windows 10. I tried copying files from ISO to a FAT32 formatted USB flash drive, making this with [woeusb](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/blob/master/README.md) and unetbootin, adding flags. After making the Windows bootable USB with unetbootin, the USB flash drive starts, but the bootloader don't *see windows files/gives only default option*.

Comment: Need to use 'woeusb' to make a bootable windows USB from ubuntu.  Think unetbootin does not work for making bootable windows USB in ubuntu.

Comment: You can use **woeusb** in text mode (command line) to create a USB pendrive that works both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185).

Answer (score 0):

If your pc is UEFI, you should:

1. Create `NTFS` filesystem on USB's first (and single) partition,
2. Set the partition type to 'Microsoft Basic Data`
3. Copy all files from ISO to USB
4. Reboot, enter boot menu and select USB's first partition to boot into

People usually make mistake of creating `FAT32` filesystem, but in most cases it does not work since windows ISO include a bigger file than the size supported by FAT32

If your pc is not UEFI, you should use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) tool to create bootable `Windows Pendrive'

Comment: Now, I need to install ubuntu, because system files is crashed xD Anyway, I will try this solution.

Comment: How I can change partition type?

Comment: @eloskowyGaming You can use `cfdisk` tool as well as `gparted` for this purpose. With `cfdisk` use `cfdisk /dev/sdaX` to open with usb. Select partition and use arrow keys to use `Type` option and change that. After that you should `Write` with write option.