# Flash Drive corrupted after try to make a Windows Installation

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, usb-drive

I tried to make a bootable windows drive with a 16GB flash drive and an error occurred making the drive unrecognizable by the system. 
I've tried all ports of the pc and not worked, tried all ports in another computer and nothing. The GParted not recognize it too.

Here is my system info:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.2.1 Desktop: Gnome 3.34.1 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 
  Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: H81M-HG4 serial: <root required> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: P1.20 date: 12/06/2013 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium G3220 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 11996 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 103.29 GiB (11.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-00BN5A0 
  size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: WD-WCC3F4594548
```

Here is the lsusb output:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Disks screen:

[image]

The drive is bootable but when I start the pc, the grub recovery opens and says that the file system is unknown. Typing ls shows some partitions like (hd,msdos5) and (hd,0). Typing ls (hd,msdos5) shows that it is ext4 but with hd,0 is unknown. Can someone help me figure how to format it?

**EDIT 1**:

lsblk -f output:

```
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop1
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop2
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop3
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop4
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/kde-
loop5
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop6
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop7
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop8
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/vlc/
loop9
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop10
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop11
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop12
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/kolo
loop13
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop14
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/vlc/
loop15
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop16
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
sda                                                                   
├─sda1
│    vfat         0575-3A5C                             503,2M     2% /boot/efi
├─sda4
│                                                                     
└─sda5
     ext4         119910cb-d423-4866-91cd-37b4a2223df7  399,2G    20% /
```

lsblk -m output:

```
sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0    956K root  disk  brw-rw----
loop1   54,7M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop2    4,2M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop3   89,1M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop4  260,7M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop5   14,8M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop6   89,1M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop7    4,2M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop8  202,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop9   54,6M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop10 156,7M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop11  44,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop12  15,8M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop13  44,2M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop14 202,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop15  14,8M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop16 160,2M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda    931,5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   512M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda4     1K root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda5 539,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

The tool used to create the install drive was WoeUSB command line.
The attributes was the following:

```
 woeusb --tgt-fs NTFS --device ISO_PATH /dev/sdb
```

After the execution, an error occurred and some files related to GRUB wasn't copied into the media.
I removed the media without "eject" it from system.

**EDIT 2:**

I have tried mkusb and it cant recognize the pendrive.
Here is the output:

```
Select version of mkusb (d/e/n/b/q) d
 dus 12.3.9 
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
 No suitable target device found 
p_target: target=/dev/
No target device or bad target device
p_clean:
wipe the first Mibibyte
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
 No suitable target device found 
p_target: target=/dev/
No target device or bad target device
p_clean:
wipe the whole device - it can take very long time
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
 No suitable target device found 
p_target: target=/dev/
No target device or bad target device
p_clean:
clean if necessary and return
clean if necessary and quit
```

The fact that the pendrive is still bootable and in the grub rescue the ls command list some of it's partitions I believe that it is still alive. But the system or any tool can't see it. Only the lsusb and drivers see the device. Maybe there is another way to format the pendrive.

Comment: 1. Which tool/method did you use to create the Windows install drive (alias boot drive)? 2. Disks is not the best tool to view USB boot drives. Please try with `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and edit the original question to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing the output of `lsblk`.

`/dev/sda5` has an ext4 file system and it is the root partition. But after that I see nothing. I had hoped to see the partitions of the USB pendrive. Maybe the pendrive was no longer plugged in.

Anyway, I have used **woeusb** with good results (to create USB install drives for Windows 10). See the following link

[WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185)

Please notice that I used and recommend `sudo`.

I suggest that you try again. This time, do not unplug the drive directly. Instead, when woeusb has finished

- Run the command **`sync`** and wait for it to finish (when the terminal window returns to prompt).
- Unmount the drive

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sdX*
  ```

  where X is the device letter from the USB pendrive, for example b, so in that case `/dev/sdb*`

After that you should be able to unplug the pendrive and use it to boot another computer.

---

If this does not work, you had better check if the pendrive is good or bad. You can analyze the status of the pendrive according to the following link

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) - the answer "Analysis ..."