# Windows 10 Live USB Stick won't boot alongside Ubuntu

Tags: boot

Currently I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my PC. I got 3 drives:

1) 256 GB SSD - Ubuntu 19.10

2) 1 TB HDD - My Data

3) 240 GB SSD - New and empty

I bought dirve no. 3 because I need (unfortunately) windows 10 to run some software that won't work on linux. The idea was to create a dual boot system.

I flashed a win10.iso via win32diskimager (on my laptop) to a USB drive and tried to boot from it. Unfortunately it doesn't boot from it, but it boots into ubuntu. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You don't say, but did you set your bios to boot from USB first?  Does the USB boot if used in the laptop?  It is good to check simple things first.

Comment: @crip659, I select boot from USB at startup in my bios manually

Comment: Would seem like PC not reading USB as bootable, would check if booting in laptop, if not, make new image using another program.

Comment: win32diskimager is a cloning tool, but cloning does not make a working boot drive from a Windows iso file. Try 1. [the brand new mkusb-plug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug) or 2. [the classic woeusb in text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185).

Comment: If you want to create the Windows installer in a Windows computer, I think it will work well to use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)

Comment: Using the windows 10 installation media creator from microsoft did the trick. I think @sudodus is correct, win32diskimager didn't create a bootable usb stick. (althrough I always use win32diskimager to flash images like ubuntu, raspbian, .... and never had a problem)

Comment: You are right. Most (but not all) Linux distros provide iso files, that are treated with isohybrid (they are [hybrid iso files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)). This means that they will work when burned to DVD disks *and* when cloned to USB pendrives and memory cards.