# Creat startup disk

Tags: boot, windows

I want to create a bootable usb. I used create startup disk program (Ubuntu default program) and I have a Windows 10 iso file. But I am not able to select it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. SDC doesn't do Windows. Rufus https://rufus.ie/ will install a working copy of Windows to USB, but it is a Windows program. Mkusb will create a Windows installer disk, if the ISO is less than 4GB.

Comment: Also I have problem with installing repos . I feel like I am stucked . Dont know what to do

Comment: Try https superuser for Windows stuff https://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: Linux: The new [**mkusb-plug**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug) from  `ppa:mkusb/unstable`the can create Windows installer USB drives also with files in the iso files exceeding 4 GiB. And as already stated, you can also use [**woeusb**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185) in Linux. -- Windows: [**Rufus**](https://rufus.ie) can do it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Format disk as NTFS and flash it with other program like WoeUSB ( https://www.fossmint.com/woeusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-sticks-from-linux/ )