# I am trying to switch from Ubuntu to windows but when I use the "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8" comand I get this:

Tags: ppa, 23.04

I am trying to switch from Ubuntu to Windows, but when I use the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` command, I get this:

[image: error message]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have not mentioned which version of Ubuntu you are using. It looks like, from the error messages, that you are using Ubuntu 23.04. This version has reached the end of standard support and is off-topic here. If you are using a supported version of Ubuntu, then [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508195/edit) with the Ubuntu version and how adding this PPA will help you moving from Ubuntu to Windows.

Comment: I think you are trying to use a deprecated ppa in order to install woeusb. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185). An alternative is to use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), which can also create a Windows installer USB system, and it is easier to install (than woeusb).

Answer (score 1):

### Always Verify PPA Information

When in doubt about any PPA, not just WebUpd8, it's always best to visit the official Launchpad Website for the PPA, and every reputable PPA has one of the form `https://launchpad.net/{PPA Name}` where PPA name will resemble the repository added in your `apt.sources` files.  In short it's everything in the entry minus `ppa.`  In WebUp8's case, it's [WebUpd8 PPA Website](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8).

Long Form For Illustration: `https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8`.

Once there for any repository,

1. Click `Technical Details about this PPA`
2. Use the handy dropdown box titled `Choose Your Ubuntu Version` as a quick check.  I've posted WebUp8's below:

[image: Available PPA Versions]

As you can see from the cropped screenshot, version 23.04 isn't supported by this PPA, whether or not the version is EOL or not is now moot.

### Verification Example Two

Just as a quick exercise, I Googled for `woeusb` and should the OP choose to follow whatever tutorial etc. was being used there is a PPA that supports Lunar (23.04).  See [Tomtomtom's WoeUSB PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/woeusb).

Long Form: `https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/woeusb`

which shows:

[image: WoeUSB Ubuntu Versions]]